# GAN Using Graph Convolution Network

Tags: neural-networks

I am using the Pokemon GAN tutorial in:

https://blog.wolfram.com/2020/08/18/generative-adversarial-networks-gans-in-the-wolfram-language/

Where convolution blocks and deconvolution blocks are given by:

[image]

[image]

In the following link, the code for a graph convolution layer is given:

[How to implement graph neural networks in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/199479/how-to-implement-graph-neural-networks-in-mathematica)

Basically, we are passing an adjacency matrix instead of an image…

```
gnn[adj_, transform_,      
    activation_ : True] := Module[{},
  NetGraph[{"fts_transf" -> NetMapOperator[transform], 
    "dot" -> DotLayer[], 
    "adj" -> 
     NetArrayLayer["Array" -> adj, LearningRateMultipliers -> None], 
    If[activation, "activation" -> Ramp, Nothing]}, {"adj" -> "dot", 
    "fts_transf" -> "dot", 
    If[activation, "dot" -> "activation", "dot" -> NetPort["Output"]]}]
  ]
```

---

> My question is what would be the associated deconvolution layer for this graph layer?

Comment: I am guessing that since the Graph Convolution Layer uses a dot product, dot products cannot be reversed... makes sense?